# Signal Spectrum MATLAB Syntax

Tags: matlab, signals, spectrum

I have a little problem regarding MATLAB and its syntaxes. I'm trying to plot a spectrum regarding an AM-modulated signal.

In my case the AM-modulation is defined as:

`y(t)=[1+m*x(t)]*cos(2*pi*fc*t)`, where fc=100 kHz and m=0.5

Breaking y(t) in parts:

```
y(t)=cos(2*pi*fc*t)+m*x(t)*cos(2*pi*fc*t)
```

and now x(t) is cosine wave with an amplitude of 1 and frequency range from fx=[0-5000Hz]. So y(t) can be written as:

```
y(t)=cos(2*pi*fc*t)+m*cos(2*pi*fx*t)*cos(2*pi*fc*t)
```

Using the trigonometric identity, we can write y(t) as:

```
cos(x)cos(y)=1/2(cos(x-y)+cos(x+y))

y(t)=cos(2*pi*fc*t)+m/2*cos(2*pi*t(fc-fx))+m/2*cos(2*pi*t(fc+fx))
```

Now when fx=[0,5000Hz], y(t) can be written as the sum of these harmonic waves:

```
y(t)=cos(2*pi*fc*t)+m/2*cos(2*pi*t(fc-0))+m/2*cos(2*pi*t(fc+0))+m/2*cos(2*pi*t(fc-1))+m/2*cos(2*pi*t(fc+1))... + m/2*cos(2*pi*t(fc-5000))+m/2*cos(2*pi*t(fc+5000))
```

Now when writing this all down in MATLAB:

```
clear all;
fc=100000; //base frequency
Fs=250000; //sampling rate should be Fs>2fc according to Nyquist criterion
Ts=1/Fs;
m=0.5;
t = 0:Ts:1-Ts;
fx= 0:1:5000;
yt=cos(2*pi*fc*t)+m*0.5*cos(2*pi*t(fc-fx))+m*0.5*cos(2*pi*t(fc+fx)) // this is where all goes wrong
plot(abs(fft(yt))); // I don't know if this is the correct way to plot it.
```

The program always states that there's an error in the line with yt, it complains something about matrix dimensions should agree. I really don't know how I can fix this prom, so any help or suggestions are really appreciated.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you are not using the [ammod](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/ammod.html?refresh=true) function?

Comment: Didn't know there was a function ammod before you mentioned it, I have to do some studying regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is because the dimensions of `t` and the dimensions of `fx` don't match.  You need to make sure that both of the dimensions of `t` and `fx` match.  Therefore, try changing `fx` to this to ensure that both arrays are the same size:

```
fx = 0:(numel(t)-1);
```